# Leetcode Search in Rotated Sorted Array

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, binary-search

I was doing [Search in sorted array question from leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array/)

### Question

Suppose an array sorted in ascending order is rotated at some pivot unknown to you beforehand.

(i.e., [0,1,2,4,5,6,7] might become [4,5,6,7,0,1,2]).

You are given a target value to search. If found in the array return its index, otherwise return -1.

You may assume no duplicate exists in the array.

Your algorithm's runtime complexity must be in the order of O(log n).

### Example

Input: nums = [4,5,6,7,0,1,2], target = 0
Output: 4

### My solution

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number}
 */
var search = function(nums, target) {
    for (let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (target === nums[i]) return i
    }
    return -1 
};
```

While this algo works, I am not sure if this is optimal or correct? for question with medium difficulty. Can someone verify it?

Comment: Hello, I have seen the leetcode site and in the description of the challenge you forgot to write the most important information : *Your algorithm's runtime complexity must be in the order of O(log n)*. Please add it to the challenge description.

Comment: @dariosicily done. Also, Isn't the complexity of the above algo 0(log n)?

Comment: Your code runs in `O(n)`, which is not fulfilling the requirement

Answer (score 1):

I start from your code:

```
var search = function(nums, target) {
    for (let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (target === nums[i]) return i
    }
    return -1 
};
```

And your question:

> While this algo works, I am not sure if this is optimal or correct?

Your algorithm is correct but it is optimal ? The answer is nope because as from the comment by @CertainPerformance to your question your code runs in O(n).

The hint is contained in the phrase *Your algorithm's runtime complexity must be in the order of O(log n)* that bounds the desired solution to the [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) having O(log n) complexity. The algorithm works if there is a sorted array, but with some modification can be adapted to a rotated array.

Here my javascript code for the original binary search:

```
const search = function search(a, t) {
    let l = 0;
    let r = a.length - 1;

    while (l <= r) {
        let m = Math.floor((l+r) /2);
        if (a[m] == t) { return m;  }
        if (a[m]  < t) { l = m + 1; }
        if (a[m]  > t) { r = m - 1; } 
   }
   return -1;
}
```

My solution for a rotated array is quite similar but with a two if else inside the while cycle because we can have four different cases, I added an explanation after the code below:

```
const search = function search(a, t) {
    let l = 0;
    let r = a.length - 1;

    while (l <= r) {
        let m = Math.floor((l+r) /2);
        if (a[m] == t) { return m; }

        if (a[m] < a[r]) {
            if (t > a[m] && t <= a[r]) { 
                l = m + 1; 
            } else { 
                r = m - 1; 
            }
        } else {
            if (t >= a[l] && t < a[m]) { 
                r = m - 1; 
            }
            else {
                l = m + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

console.log(search([4,5,6,7,0,1,2], 0));
console.log(search([4,5,6,7,0,1,2], 5));
console.log(search([4,5,6,7,0,1,2], 3));
console.log(search([1, 3], 3));
console.log(search([4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3], 8));
```

Substantially if I have a [l,..m, .. r] interval I have two possible cases:

1. a[m] < a[r] --> consecutive ascending numbers, so if a[m] < t <=
   a[r] in the next iteration I will examine the interval [m + 1, r]
   otherwise I will examine the interval [l, r - 1]
2. a[m] >= a[r] --> there are rotated elements like for example [7, 0,
   1, 2] , so I am sure the left array contains only ascending numbers.
   In this case if a[l] <= a[t] < a[m] in the next iteration I will
   examine the interval [l, m - 1] otherwise I will examine the
   interval [m + 1, r].